# how to convert datatable to List <String>?

Tags: c#, list

I tried with this code but was not able to do it :

```
SPDatalogic sp = new SPDatalogic(); //datalogic class
List<String> dt = new List<String>();
dt = sp.CheckProduct(id); //Datatable

List<String> list = new List<String>();

SPBusinesslogic ab = new SPBusinesslogic();  //businesslogic class
String prod;
prod = ab.CheckProduct(id);                   
list.Add(prod);

return list;
```

got simple error like cannot covert datatable to string
i have no idea about how to do it.

Errors :
Error 1:

> Cannot implicitly convert type
>   'System.Collections.Generic.List' to 'string'

Error 2:

> Cannot implicitly convert type 'System.Data.DataTable' to
>   'System.Collections.Generic.List'

Comment: Could you give us the full error please?

Comment: Please give us the full error, update your question with it. **Don't post it as a comment**. And why are you looping over `dt.Rows` if you're not doing anything with the rows?

Comment: ab.CheckProduct(id); probably does not return a string. You could maybe use ab.CheckProduct(id).toString(); to convert it to string depending on the data it usually returns.

Comment: Do you have to change `List<String> dt = new List<String>();` to `DataTable dt = sp.CheckProduct(id);`

Comment: @MikeChristensen in order to compare the values of textbox with datatable i want to convert it to list<string>

Comment: @mason are you good with it now?

Comment: No, because I'm not sure where your DataTable (you mentioned on in the title) even is. Your "Error 3" is referring to something that has Rows, but your code doesn't show that. Please show us exactly what code you're using and exactly what errors you're getting. Confusingly, you've also named a `List<string>` as dt, which is commonly used the variable name for an instance of a DataTable.

Comment: @mason  declared it first as datatable in order to check whether i am able to set datatable to list i changed it to list.
my Datatable is CheckProduct(String id)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There appear to be quite a few errors with this code.  Let's start with the top part:

```
SPDatalogic sp = new SPDatalogic(); //datalogic class
List<String> dt = new List<String>();
dt = sp.CheckProduct(id);
List<String> list = new List<String>();
```

`dt` is obviously a `List<String>`, and `sp.CheckProduct()` is obviously returning a `DataTable`, which of course cannot be implicitly converted to a `List<String>`.  You later seem to want to iterate through the `Rows` property of the `DataTable` anyway.  So, that must be fixed:

```
SPDatalogic sp = new SPDatalogic(); //datalogic class
DataTable dt;
dt = sp.CheckProduct(id);
List<String> list = new List<String>();
```

You'll now be able to loop through `dt.Rows` to build your `List<>`.

```
foreach (DataRow dr in dt.Rows)
{
    SPBusinesslogic ab = new SPBusinesslogic();  //businesslogic class
    string prod;
    prod = ab.CheckProduct(id);                   
    list.Add(prod);
}
```

This should work fine (though I doubt there's any reason you need to declare `ab` inside the loop), however it's unclear what `id` is.  Perhaps that's some sort of column within your row?  If so, you'd probably want something like:

```
var id = dr["id"];
string prod = ab.CheckProduct(id);
list.Add(prod);
```

This, of course, assumes `ab.CheckProduct()` takes an object and returns a string.  You'll need to post the method signature for `CheckProduct()` if that isn't working.

Comment: For the OP, it is confusing to have `CheckProduct()` return a `string` in one class and a `List<string>` in another class.  A better approach would be to use `CheckProductList()` (or simply `CheckProducts()`) where a list is indicated.

Comment: thanks. id is in my sense invoice number through will i will fetch products  of that particular invoice

Comment: almost there! i still have 1 error 

Cannot implicitly convert type 'System.Collections.Generic.List<string>' to 'string'

Comment: If `SPBusinesslogic.CheckProduct()` returns a `List<String>` that you want to add all elements of into `list`, you can use `list.AddRange(ab.CheckProduct(id));`